# Remove all the tree from the parent removed cell in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Here is the case:
I want to remove all the cells connected to a cell and its children and the children of their children, etc.
How can I do that in mxGraph?

Comment: Are you referring to www.draw.io???

Comment: draw.io is a web application, not a developer library/tool. The question appears to be a usage question of a web app. Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: No guys, I have downloaded the library and I am using it in my web application

Comment: @ShaheMasoyan draw.io is not a library, are you referring to mxGraph, maybe?

Comment: yes @David, that is what I mean

Comment: @David, by children I don't mean the vertex children of the cell, I mean the cells connected to a specific cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See deleteSubtree in javascript/examples/orgchart.html